# Can SSMS display empty space as a character?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Right now I'm working on a dataset where I would like to return records where a certain field is NOT NULL. The dataset is result of a table join.

My resulting set is still returning records where the field I told not to return NULL look empty. I'd like to see what the true value in these records are since they don't seem to be true NULL.

Is there a way to get Management Studio to show spaces as a character just so I can see what's in there if anything?

Comment: I checked and there is no space in the field (the value) and its not null. For some reason doing WHERE ColName <> '' worked. I upped gbn's answer since it was close. Thanks!

Comment: NOTE: After the <> that is two single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.

You'll have to modify the query.
Use replace to turn spaces into something else?

```
REPLACE(MyCol, ' ', '#')
```

Comment: Do I have to declare that at the top of the whole query or can I put it like this:
WHERE REPLACE(DischargeDateTime,' ', '#') IS NOT NULL

Comment: It would be in the SELECT REPLACE(DischargeDateTime,' ', '#') FROm MYTable WHERE DischargeDateTime IS NOT NULL